# MS WebBrowser control and IE10 are getting different HTML/CSS for the same Url

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

I have found that the MS WebBrowser control hosted by C# WinForm running on Win8 Prof system and IE10 running on the same Win8 Prof system do get different HTML/CSS for the same target URL:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1430228539/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new

Here are screenshots:

[image: Target URL page rendered by WebBrowser Control]

[image: Target URL page rendered by IE10]

Could you please advise me on how to make the WebBrowser control get the same HTML/CSS as IE10 does?

FYI: Setting 'User-Agent' attribute for WebBrowser control navigation call didn't work here.

Addition: I have just checked making simple Win8 AppStore local test app hosting WebView control; it does render the same HTML/CSS as IE10 does.

Comment: Is it actually different HTML, or just different rendering?

Comment: @svick Different HTML/CSS, and the differences are very broad, e.g. the first HTML/CSS set (obtained by WebBrowser control) does use HTML tables (TABLE, TR, TD etc. HTML tags/elements) for layouting and the second HTML/CSS set (obtained by IE10) does use HTML DIV tags/elements for layouting.

Comment: the webbrowser control sends a different user agent. It stuck with IE7 mode unless you turn on FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Comment: @ShengJiang: thank you, I tried to use FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION as proposed here [http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) but it didn't help: the rendered layout was the same for all the option values.